# DCount returning wrong record count when filtering by dates

Tags: ms-access, vba, dcount

Trying to get a count of all records from a table called "ComplaintsListMaster" that have a "ComplaintDate" greater than 11/1/2015. The correct value is around 70. But when I use the dcount pasted below, it returns 3951 which is almost every record in the table.

`DCount("[ID]", "[ComplaintsListMaster]", "[ComplaintDate] >= 11/1/2015")`

Any obvious mistakes?

We use an MS Access front end for a SQL Server backend

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following:

```
DCount("[ID]", "[ComplaintsListMaster]", "[ComplaintDate] >= #" & 11/1/2015 & "#")
```

dates are enclosed within the `#date#` number signs, in a similar way to how strings are enclosed in single quotes/apostrophe symbols `'string'`.

Im not sure why you need both equal or greater than symbol `=>11/1/2015` though. I would personally use `>10/1/2015`.

```
DCount("[ID]", "[ComplaintsListMaster]", "[ComplaintDate] > #" & 10/1/2015 & "#")
```

But both should work, so just personal preference I guess.

> EDIT

I have just realised that I assumed dd/mm/yyyy and there was a possibility you are using mm/dd/yyyy so in that case, my answer would be `>10/31/2015`.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose date in `#`, and always write your dates the US way (mm/dd/yyyy) in VBA:

```
DCount("[ID]", "[ComplaintsListMaster]", "[ComplaintDate] >= #11/1/2015#")
```

Means >= Nov-1.
The SQL Server backend has no impact in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the date hardcoded, so follow this general guide.

Also, `DCount` needs no field to look up:

```
Dim FilterDate    As Date
Dim FilterDateSql As String

FilterDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
FilterDateSql = Format(FilterDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
DCount("*", "[ComplaintsListMaster]", "[ComplaintDate] >= #" & FilterDateSql & "#")
```